# Print Prime Numbers (2,3,5,7)

Tags: javascript, numbers, task

I found the code for solving this problem, but I cannot figure out the logic of the solution.

```
let n = 10;

nextPrime:
for (let i = 2; i <= n; i++) { 
 for (let j = 2; j < i; j++) { 
  if (i % j == 0) continue nextPrime; 
  }
 alert( i ); 
}
```

I can't understand how the second for works, if it has an increment like the first, then the result should have been all numbers from 2 to 10, since the beginning of both for is the same number (2) ..
Can you please explain each iteration, for example why 4 is not displayed?

Comment: the key is in what `continue nextPrime` does.

Comment: Can you please explain each iteration, for example why 4 is not displayed?

Comment: When `i` is divisble by `j`, the `continue nextPrime;` statement exits the inner loop and moves on to the next iteration of the outer loop.

Answer (score 1):

It’s using label to break the inner loop when it finds number is not prime . Outer loop is iterating the number and inner loop checks if it’s divisible between 2 to number.

[Label break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)

Answer (score 1):

the **continue nextPrime** used for just continue in the loop to the next iteration without finish all the code inside the loop.
like:

```
data:
for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) { 
  if(i === 2)
      continue data;
 console.log(i)
}
```

here when I get to I equal to 2 the code continue to the next number without continue to the rest of the code